# How to upload file by using java web services

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload

How to upload file by using java web services.

I have try with FileUplaod java jar. But failed.

Comment: This is a very good example of how NOT to ask a question. I am not even going to bother pointing out what's wrong with this way of asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, are you spelling `FileUpload` correctly?